# how to know format of command for sublime text 3 keyboard bindings

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3

I looked at the [key binding](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html) doc for sublime text 3, and I change some of the existing key bindings.. however, I would like to create a keybinding for the command `project-> new workspace for project`.. following the pattern of commands in the file, I assumed that the command is the same that appears on the menu dropdown list and by replacing spaces with `_`.

[image]

So this is what I did:

```
{ "keys": ["super+shift+t"], "command": "new_workspace_for_project" }
```

unfortunately it does't work! (p.s. I edited the file that appears after selecting `preferences->Key Bindings - User`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if another plugin is using the above keymaps all you have to do is open the ST console (ctrl+`) and write out sublime.log_commands(True) and that will log all the commands ran in ST.

Comment: and your short cut is being used already for the default { "keys": ["super+shift+t"], "command": "reopen_last_file" }. Try a different combination to see if it is the conflict that is causing this to not work.